# How to remove character strings that are detected/contained within other character strings, but only within a specified group_by()-argument

Tags: r, string, dataframe, group-by, tidyverse

Let's say I have:

```
> w
   digest    gene          seq
1     InS  AB0583          AAB
2     InS  AB0583        AABKR
3     InS  AB0583      GFHGHGG
4     PAC PU83022          EUT
5     PAC PU83022      HSFSFJF
6     PAC PU83022        EUTCK
7     PAC PU83022       EUTCKJ
8     InS PO93853         HDGJ
9     InS PO93853        HDGJU
10    InS PO93853       YTYEYD
11    InS PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG
12    InS PO93853   SALGHAGGEE
```

I have applied two different methods to identify proteins (decoded with their gene name, `w$gene`). The methods are encoded in `w$digest`. As you can see, there may be overlapping sequences of `w$seq` within each `w$gene` within each `w$digest` - e.g. `EUT` is also within `EUTCK`, which is within `EUTCKJ`.

I want to know how many unique amino acids, each letter in `w$seq`, were identified. Therefore, I need to remove any/all character string(s) that where detected within another character string, but only when `grouped_by(digest, gene)`. The character string with most characters should be kept.

I seek a solution in `tidyverse`

**Help need:**

(1) Count the number of characters, and arrange as follows:

```
w <- w %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(seq)) %>%
  arrange(digest, gene, count)
```

So that

```
> w
   digest    gene          seq count
1     InS  AB0583          AAB     3
2     InS  AB0583        AABKR     5
3     InS  AB0583      GFHGHGG     7
4     InS PO93853         HDGJ     4
5     InS PO93853        HDGJU     5
6     InS PO93853       YTYEYD     6
```

(2) `group_by(digest, gene)`, and now **remove** rows that contain a `w$seq` that is detected within another `w$seq` (within this grouping), and keep the row where the `w$seq` has most characters.

**Output**

```
> w
   digest    gene          seq count
1     InS  AB0583          AAB     3 #* found within:
2     InS  AB0583        AABKR     5 #*
3     InS  AB0583      GFHGHGG     7
4     InS PO93853         HDGJ     4 #** found within:
5     InS PO93853        HDGJU     5 #**
6     InS PO93853       YTYEYD     6 #***
7     InS PO93853   SALGHAGGEE    10
8     InS PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12 #***
9     PAC PU83022          EUT     3 #****
10    PAC PU83022        EUTCK     5 #****
11    PAC PU83022       EUTCKJ     6 #****
12    PAC PU83022      HSFSFJF     7
```

Therefore, **Expected output**

```
> w
   digest    gene          seq count
1     InS  AB0583        AABKR     5 
2     InS  AB0583      GFHGHGG     7
3     InS PO93853        HDGJU     5 
4     InS PO93853   SALGHAGGEE    10
5     InS PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12 
6     PAC PU83022       EUTCKJ     6 
7     PAC PU83022      HSFSFJF     7
```

**Data**

```
w <- data.frame(
  digest = c(rep("InS", 3), rep("PAC", 4), rep("InS", 5)),
  gene = c(rep("AB0583", 3), rep("PU83022", 4), rep("PO93853", 5)),
  seq = c("AAB", "AABKR", "GFHGHGG",
          "EUT", "HSFSFJF", "EUTCK", "EUTCKJ",
          "HDGJ", "HDGJU", "YTYEYD", "YTYEYDJHSGSG", "SALGHAGGEE")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each group in `group_by()` you could make a new list column where each row contains all the `seq` values for that group.  You could then do a row-wise operation where you count the number of times each value of `seq` shows up in all the values.  Keeping the ones that only show up once will give you the result you want.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
w <- data.frame(
  digest = c(rep("InS", 3), rep("PAC", 4), rep("InS", 5)),
  gene = c(rep("AB0583", 3), rep("PU83022", 4), rep("PO93853", 5)),
  seq = c("AAB", "AABKR", "GFHGHGG",
          "EUT", "HSFSFJF", "EUTCK", "EUTCKJ",
          "HDGJ", "HDGJU", "YTYEYD", "YTYEYDJHSGSG", "SALGHAGGEE")
)

w <- w %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(seq)) %>%
  arrange(digest, gene, count) 

w %>% group_by(digest, gene) %>%
  mutate(all_vals = list(seq)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(win = sum(grepl(seq, all_vals))) %>% 
  filter(win == 1) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-c(win, all_vals))
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#> # Rowwise:  digest, gene
#>   digest gene    seq          count
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 InS    AB0583  AABKR            5
#> 2 InS    AB0583  GFHGHGG          7
#> 3 InS    PO93853 HDGJU            5
#> 4 InS    PO93853 SALGHAGGEE      10
#> 5 InS    PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12
#> 6 PAC    PU83022 EUTCKJ           6
#> 7 PAC    PU83022 HSFSFJF          7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### Edit:

Here is a potential solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

w <- data.frame(
  digest = c(rep("InS", 3), rep("PAC", 4), rep("InS", 5)),
  gene = c(rep("AB0583", 3), rep("PU83022", 4), rep("PO93853", 5)),
  seq = c("AAB", "AABKR", "GFHGHGG",
          "EUT", "HSFSFJF", "EUTCK", "EUTCKJ",
          "HDGJ", "HDGJU", "YTYEYD", "YTYEYDJHSGSG", "SALGHAGGEE")
)

w %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(seq)) %>%
  arrange(digest, gene, count) %>%
  group_by(digest, gene) %>%
  filter(str_count(paste0(seq, collapse = "_"), seq) == 1)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#> # Groups:   digest, gene [3]
#>   digest gene    seq          count
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 InS    AB0583  AABKR            5
#> 2 InS    AB0583  GFHGHGG          7
#> 3 InS    PO93853 HDGJU            5
#> 4 InS    PO93853 SALGHAGGEE      10
#> 5 InS    PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12
#> 6 PAC    PU83022 EUTCKJ           6
#> 7 PAC    PU83022 HSFSFJF          7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

### Original answer:

This is a bit awkward, but it 'works':

```r
library(tidyverse)

w <- data.frame(
  digest = c(rep("InS", 3), rep("PAC", 4), rep("InS", 5)),
  gene = c(rep("AB0583", 3), rep("PU83022", 4), rep("PO93853", 5)),
  seq = c("AAB", "AABKR", "GFHGHGG",
          "EUT", "HSFSFJF", "EUTCK", "EUTCKJ",
          "HDGJ", "HDGJU", "YTYEYD", "YTYEYDJHSGSG", "SALGHAGGEE")
)

w %>%
  mutate(count = str_count(seq)) %>%
  arrange(digest, gene, count) %>%
  group_by(digest, gene) %>%
  mutate(strings = paste0(seq, collapse = "|")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(strings = gsub(paste0("\\b", seq, "\\b"), "", strings)) %>%
  filter(!grepl(seq, strings)) %>%
  select(-strings) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   digest gene    seq          count
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>        <int>
#> 1 InS    AB0583  AABKR            5
#> 2 InS    AB0583  GFHGHGG          7
#> 3 InS    PO93853 HDGJU            5
#> 4 InS    PO93853 SALGHAGGEE      10
#> 5 InS    PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12
#> 6 PAC    PU83022 EUTCKJ           6
#> 7 PAC    PU83022 HSFSFJF          7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using *base*:

```
# add count and sort
w$count <- nchar(w$seq)
w <- w[ with(w, order(digest, gene, count)), ]

# subset
w[ sapply(Map(grepl, w$seq, ave(w$seq, w[ 1:2 ], FUN = list)), sum) == 1, ]
#    digest    gene          seq count
# 2     InS  AB0583        AABKR     5
# 3     InS  AB0583      GFHGHGG     7
# 9     InS PO93853        HDGJU     5
# 12    InS PO93853   SALGHAGGEE    10
# 11    InS PO93853 YTYEYDJHSGSG    12
# 7     PAC PU83022       EUTCKJ     6
# 5     PAC PU83022      HSFSFJF     7
```